# Logic in factorial recursion call

Tags: javascript, wordpress, recursion, factorial

I'm working to wrap my head around recursion and maybe I'm being too obsessive, but here goes:

In the javascript code

```
var factorial = function(number) {
  // If the number is negative, it doesn't have a factorial. Return an
  // impossible value to indicate this.
  if (number < 0) {
    return -1;
  }

  // If the number is zero, its factorial is one.
  if (number === 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  // If the number is neither illegal nor zero, call factorial again,
  // this time passing in a smaller number. Eventually we'll reach 0,
  // causing each call to return to its caller and the recursion terminates.

  return number * factorial(number - 1);
};

factorial(5);
```

The recursive function returns 120 as expected, but why?

In drawing out the logic, 2 things trip me up: 1) Why is this even operable and 2) Though it is operable, why wouldn't it return -1?

1) Why is this even operable?:

In drawing this out and plugging 5 as an argument, in the return statement at the bottom, we get return 5 * factorial(5 - 1). Why does this equate to 20 as expected? Aren't we calling the function to return 5 * the value of **factorial**(5-1)? How can we multiply 5 by the value of something that hasn't even been determined yet? If this was simply 5 * (5-1) = 20, then that's obvious or even factorial(5) * (5-1) = 20 makes sense..

2)Though it is operable, why doesn't it return -1?:

As with the case above, eventually, we'll get to the point in the recursion where it'll look like 1 * factorial(1-1)... 1 * (1-1) = 0. And with this function plugging the number in to itself for operation, and with our base case saying "if the integer plugged in is zero, stop operation and return -1". Why isn't that happening here?

Apologies if this seems simple, I may be making it a bigger deal than in needs to be. I just want to learn :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question - glad you're diving into recursion head on!

Let's walk through what's going on:

We start with `factorial(5)`. This returns `5 * factorial(5-1)` as you pointed out. In order to understand what `factorial(5-1)` is, we have to call the `factorial` function again.

`factorial(5-1)` returns `4 * factorial(4-1)`. Let's substitute that in to what we have above. That gives us `5 * 4 * factorial(4-1)`.  Again we do `factorial(4-1)` and substitute that in. Which gives us `5 * 4 * 3 * factorial(3-1)`.

If we continue we get `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorial(2-1)` and then `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * factorial(1-1)`.

Now something different happens here. `factorial(1-1)` returns `1` per the if condition:

```
// If the number is zero, its factorial is one.
if (number === 0) {
    return 1;
}
```

So we have `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1` which = 120 = 5! as we expect. We're never going to hit the `number == -1` if condition unless we put in a negative number. For any positive number, the `number == 0` condition will catch every time.

Comment: Aha! Wow, thanks so much for the clear explanation winhowes. Many thanks to you!!

Comment: @jb07 if this is the correct answer - would you mind marking it as so? Thanks!

Comment: Got it. Hope I did that right (I still don't have the 'rep' to upvote yet :) )

Answer (score 2):

To add to winhowes' answer

> How can we multiply 5 by the value of something that hasn't even been determined yet?

Well, we don't, not until we know the value of `factorial(5-1)`. When `factorial(5-1)` is called, we don't actually do the multiplication yet, until we have a definite answer for that. So the 5 stays there and waits for the result of the function call to come back, but then the 4 also waits for `factorial(4-1)`.. etc. Once the final call (i.e. `factorial(1)`) returns a definitive answer, it multiplies by whatever was waiting for it, and that in turn goes and multiplies with the previous waiting call.

So you have a top-down call of methods, and when you have the values, a bottom-up of multiplications occur. As illustrated in this diagram:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for illustrating this! It's useful for me to see the order in which the operations take place. Any recommendations on books/resources that will fill in these sorts of gaps as you did above?

Comment: you would be able to find tons of books out there that would explain recursion and other 'fundamental' parts of general programming, but unfortunately I cannot really point anything out specifically. I've just learnt these at uni, but Googling is really your best bet in this case. recursion is definitely one of the confusing bits when you start out with programming, but you're doing the best by not just letting it go if it does the job, but actually try to understand what is really happening. That will do you a lot of good :) so keep it up.

Comment: also, if you think my answer helped you in some ways, please feel free to upvote it :)